# #selector inside object extension - unresolved itendifier

Tags: selector, swift2

Using the new 2.2 version of Swift, I cannot use the `#selector` to invoke a method defined inside an extension from the (same) extension. The compiler says *unresolved itendifier* for `doSomething(_:)`.

```
extension UIViewController {

func doSomething(){
    //...
}

func setTapGestureRecognizer(){
    let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doSomething(_:))) //unresolved itendifier 
    view.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer )
}

}
```

I already tried to mark the method `doSomething()` with `@objc` without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your func has no input parameters.
Fix it to:

```
func setTapGestureRecognizer(){
    let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doSomething))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
}
```

Comment: That's it! My fault.